# JSF 2 - Using a custom action-listener to reset ajax submitted values so new values are pulled from model attributes

Tags: jsf, richfaces, el

I'm using JSF 2 Mojarra, RichFaces 4.1, and EL 2.2, deployed to a Tomcat 7 server.

On my page, I have two a4j:regions contained in the same form.  The top region is a dataTable list of entities.  The bottom region is a detail editor panel.  You select an entity from the list, and its details load in the edit panel.  The detail panel has its own validation rules and submit buttons.  I've now run into the reasonably well-known issue of JSF not resetting the submitted values with validation errors when I load a second entity into the detail form.

In researching to solve this problem, I came across [this blog from BalusC](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2012/03/reset-non-processed-input-components-on.html). He breaks the reset problem down very well and recommends [this JSF 2 action-listener](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/master/src/org/omnifaces/eventlistener/ResetInputAjaxActionListener.java) to solve the issue.

I incorporated the ResetInputAjaxActionListener into my project as a action-listener defined in my faces-config.xml.  Now, however, the code is failing where without the listener, it is working (just not resetting the submitted/local/model values).

My JSF page contains a dataTable and each row has an edit commandLink to load the row's entity into the editor:

```
<a4j:commandLink action="#{editController.load(entity.id)}" render="@form" execute="@this" value="Edit"/>
```

Since I'm using EL 2.2, I'm passing the entity's primary key directly into the load method.  Without the action-listener, this works as expected.  However, when I enable the action-listener, the code throws the following exception:

```
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: #{editController.load(entity.id)}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:110)
at com.buksoft.automaint.web.util.ResetInputAjaxActionListener.processAction(ResetInputAjaxActionListener.java:163)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at org.richfaces.component.RowKeyContextEventWrapper.broadcast(RowKeyContextEventWrapper.java:104)
at org.richfaces.component.UIDataAdaptor.broadcast(UIDataAdaptor.java:452)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
... 51 more
Caused by: javax.faces.el.MethodNotFoundException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:104)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
at org.apache.el.util.ReflectionUtil.isAssignableFrom(ReflectionUtil.java:299)
at org.apache.el.util.ReflectionUtil.getMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:172)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:251)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
... 59 more
```

It looks to me like the the EL argument value is getting set to null, which is causing a NullPointerException when EL tries to bind null to the action method's parameter, which is expected an Long value.

Now for the part that's really got me stumped.  To narrow down the error, I commented out the functionality of the ResetInputAjaxActionListener so that it was basically read-only.  What I found is that if these lines of the findAndAddEditableValueHolders() method execute, then the exception is thrown by the ActionListenerImpl.processAction() called after the ResetInputAjaxActionListener completes:

```
if (target instanceof EditableValueHolder) {
    inputs.add((EditableValueHolder) target);
}
else if (context.getIdsToVisit() != VisitContext.ALL_IDS) {
    // Render ID didn't point an EditableValueHolder. Visit all children as well.
    findAndAddEditableValueHolders(VisitContext.createVisitContext(
    context.getFacesContext(), null, context.getHints()), target, inputs);
}
```

See the findAndAddEditableValueHolders() method in the ResetInputAjaxActionListener class linked above.

And the trouble code is really only in the else if, which really confuses me because it's a recursive call back to the method itself.  It's almost if the createVisitContext() method is somehoe modifying the backing view tree.  As I said, if I strip out all mutating code that makes any real changes, and just execute this tree visit code (read-only), the exception is thrown down the line.

Can anyone explain how visiting the component tree (and not modifying anything in it), could break the EL method argument functionality?

Comment: did you solve this problem ?